# Capybara.. launching browser failing saying nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: selenium, capybara

I am running capybara2.10 with ruby 2.4.1. browser launching is failing throwing error..

```
/Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:178:in `getaddrinfo': getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known (SocketError)
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/platform.rb:178:in `localhost'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/service.rb:48:in `initialize'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/marionette/driver.rb:41:in `new'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/marionette/driver.rb:41:in `initialize'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31:in `new'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/driver.rb:31:in `new'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:52:in `for'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.9.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:23:in `browser'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:49:in `visit'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:274:in `visit'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/vendor/bundle/gems/capybara-2.18.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
    from /Users/<user>/Documents/<project>/features/step_definitions/test1.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Adding this `127.0.0.1   localhost` in `/etc/hosts` is fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

The line of code being run there is

```
info = Socket.getaddrinfo 'localhost', 80, Socket::AF_INET, Socket::SOCK_STREAM
```

For the error you are seeing to occur, that means 'localhost' isn't resolving on whatever machine you're running this on. Did you happen to remove it from your `/etc/hosts` file or something??